# "brew install dynamodb-local" causes "No formulae found in taps"

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, homebrew, dynamo-local

Full output:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "dynamodb-local" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Homebrew version 1.1.10

OS version 10.11.6

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5):

Amazon distributes DynamoDB Local on their [documentation website](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html) and over a custom Maven repository (details also in the documentation website), but not with Homebrew.

Answer (score 5):

Since amazon stopped producing versioned links and the package is technically not opened sourced the homebrew maintainers removed it.  More info here https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/9175.